# Hidden Inputs for Paypal adding Whitespace

Tags: paypal

My Paypal code for my button is shown below. On the page, all of the input lines are showing as white space. I do not want any white space showing for these lines. The live version may be viewed at: http://000lup6.wcomhost.com/wordpress1/arrowmaster/

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;"><input name="on0" type="hidden" value="RH/LH" />RH/LH</td>
<td><select name="os0">
<option value="Right Handed">Right Handed</option>
<option value="Left Handed">Left Handed</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" type="image" />
<img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
<input name="add" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="rod@safarituff.com" />
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="ARROWMASTER Quiver" />
<input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="AM-001" />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="124.99" />
<input name="page_style" type="hidden" value="Primary" />
<input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://www.safarituff.com/success.html" />
<input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://www.safarituff.com/cancel.html" />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="US" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-ShopCartBF" />

</form>
```

Comment: Where is this code going? In the editor? In that case you'll need to remove all the line breaks between them.

Comment: There are `<br/>` tags inbetween your input elements